# Yii2 establecer en el main precision de decima

Tags: php, yii2, yii

estoy intentando crear en el main.php dentro del formatter poner que coja la un valor despues de la coma:

```
<?php
 return [
'aliases' => [
    '@bower' => '@vendor/bower-asset',
    '@npm'   => '@vendor/npm-asset',
    'api' => dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/api'
],
'vendorPath' => dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/vendor',
'components' => [
    'formatter' => [
        'dateFormat' => 'dd/MM/yyyy',
        'decimalSeparator' => ',',
        'thousandSeparator' => '.',
        'currencyCode' => 'EUR',
        'numberFormatterOptions ' => [
            NumberFormatter::MIN_FRACTION_DIGITS => 0,
            NumberFormatter::MAX_FRACTION_DIGITS => 1,
        ]
    ],
    'cache' => [
        'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
    ],
],
'bootstrap' => [
    'api\modules\v1\Bootstrap',
 ]
];
```

> Fatal error: Class 'NumberFormatter' not found in

Pero este codigo no me funciona, alguien me puede ayudar? Gracias!

Comment: El error que te da es de no encontrar la clase , estas seguro que la clase esta importada use yii\i18n\Formatter ? @David

Comment: @danit Como importo el Formatter? Si pongo " use yii\i18n\Formatter " me da el mismo error.

Comment: ok , primero el archivo no es main.php sino que es config/web.php que es el archivo de configuracion general no? @David

Comment: Lo estoy haciendo en common/config/main.php. @danit

Comment: El error esta en el nombre tienes 'numberFormatterOptions ' con un espacio extra @David , al menos en el codigo que muestras

Comment: Si tenia este error, lo acabo de corregir y me sale el mismo error el problmema esta en NumberFormatter

Comment: He encontrado el problema, se tiene que activar la extension php_intl.dll (en windows). Gracias por l'ayuda @danit

Answer (score 0):

La configuración tiene un pequeño fallo en el componente `formatter` la opcion `'numberFormatterOptions '` tiene un **espacio** extra